# How create stored tsvector for jsonb and text[] array type columns?

Tags: postgresql

Can somone help me to get the syntax for creating a stored tsvector column for text[] and jsonb type columns. Specifically I am looking for what will go inside the () ?

For text[]
search_vector tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS (array_to_tsvector(<what should go here ???>)) STORED,

For jsonb
search_vector tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS (jsonb_to_tsvector(<what should go here ???>)) STORED,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the following example helps.

text[] example:

```
create table experiment1 (
  some_id text PRIMARY KEY,
  flags text[],
  flags_tsv tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS (array_to_tsvector(flags)) STORED
);
insert into experiment1 (some_id, flags)
values
('A', '{"red", "blue"}'),
('B', '{"blue", "yellow"}')
```

jsonb example:

```
create table experiment2 (
  some_id text PRIMARY KEY,
  flags jsonb,
  flags_tsv tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS (jsonb_to_tsvector('english', flags, '["string"]')) STORED
);
insert into experiment2 (some_id, flags)
values
('A', '["red", "blue"]'),
('B', '["blue", "yellow"]')
```